# how to design view like Progress bar which is fix in android?

Tags: android, progress-bar, progressdialog

I have to design my view like this

[image]

Please help me how to design this in android

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2):

To add a Button:

Open “res/layout/main.xml” file, just add normal button for demonstration.

File : res/layout/main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnStartProgress"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Download File" />

</LinearLayout>
```

2.Code

The key to use progress bar is using “Thread” to run your time consume task and another “Thread” to update the progress bar status accordingly. Read the code’s comment, it should be self-explanatory.

File : MyAndroidAppActivity.java

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

public class MyAndroidAppActivity extends Activity {

    Button btnStartProgress;
    ProgressDialog progressBar;
    private int progressBarStatus = 0;
    private Handler progressBarHandler = new Handler();

    private long fileSize = 0;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        addListenerOnButton();

    }

    public void addListenerOnButton() {

        btnStartProgress = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnStartProgress);
        btnStartProgress.setOnClickListener(
                 new OnClickListener() {

           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {

            // prepare for a progress bar dialog
            progressBar = new ProgressDialog(v.getContext());
            progressBar.setCancelable(true);
            progressBar.setMessage("File downloading ...");
            progressBar.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
            progressBar.setProgress(0);
            progressBar.setMax(100);
            progressBar.show();

            //reset progress bar status
            progressBarStatus = 0;

            //reset filesize
            fileSize = 0;

            new Thread(new Runnable() {
              public void run() {
                while (progressBarStatus < 100) {

                  // process some tasks
                  progressBarStatus = doSomeTasks();

                  // your computer is too fast, sleep 1 second
                  try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                  } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                  }

                  // Update the progress bar
                  progressBarHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                      progressBar.setProgress(progressBarStatus);
                    }
                  });
                }

                // ok, file is downloaded,
                if (progressBarStatus >= 100) {

                    // sleep 2 seconds, so that you can see the 100%
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(2000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    // close the progress bar dialog
                    progressBar.dismiss();
                }
              }
               }).start();

               }

                });

        }

    // file download simulator... a really simple
    public int doSomeTasks() {

        while (fileSize <= 1000000) {

            fileSize++;

            if (fileSize == 100000) {
                return 10;
            } else if (fileSize == 200000) {
                return 20;
            } else if (fileSize == 300000) {
                return 30;
            }
            // ...add your own

        }

        return 100;

    }

}
```